# Read CSV file and print out each value to .txt file

Tags: php, csv

Hi I have a CSV file(data.csv) and the structure inside the csv file are as follows:

names

Standard bank

ABSA bank

Capitec bank

I want to output each bank name to a .txt file. My ouput of my code currenlty are one .txt file but all 3 bank names are inside the .txt file.

```
    $row = 1;

    //Open data.csv file and create CSVData.txt file
    if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) && $myfile = fopen("CSVData.txt", "w")) {

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;

            foreach($data as $value){

                $myArray = explode(';', $value);

                $newArray = count($myArray);

                for($x = 0; $x < $newArray; $x++){
                    print_r($myArray[$x] . "<br />");
                    fputcsv($myfile, array($myArray[$x]));
                }

            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
```

Can anyone please give some help to output the three bank names to each own .txt file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: The `for($x = 0; $x < $newArray; $x++){` loop doesn't exclude them or filter them to separate files.  Adjust that part of the routine.

Answer (score 0):

use this library its awesome https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php it will give you `limit` and `columns` option to select

```
$csv = new parseCSV('data.csv');
print_r($csv->data);
```